# How to put button inside line?

Tags: html, css

What i want is to have something like this :

-------------------button------------------

I know how to put text inside line but when i put button it not looks good. Any suggestion?

Comment: *I know how to put text inside line*, then show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Add a screenshot, i didn't see the problem: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zKqaNP

Comment: i want horizontal line on both side like <hr /> not -------- its just example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add line with using `after` and `before`.

```css
button {
  padding: 0 100px;
  overflow: hidden
}
button span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
button > span:after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1000%;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100% + 5px);
  top: calc(50% - 1px);
}
button > span:before {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1000%;
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(100% + 5px);
  top: calc(50% - 1px);
}
```

```html
<button type="button">
  <span>Button</span>
</button>
```